# Dataframe columns Concatenate

Tags: python, concatenation

I have a sample data here:

[image: sample_data]

The end result I want is a new column having concatenation of the both columns.
The result should be like:

```
1. for N AM => N AM (East)
2. for EUR => N EUR
3. for ASIA => S.E. ASIA
```

P.S. I tried almost everything, if-else, np.where etc.. etc..

Comment: Can you provide a [minimally reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

```
sample_data['x'] = sample_data['Origin Region1'] + sample_data['Org_Region']
```